# SwingUtilities.invokeLater in AWT Event Dispatching Thread

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety

Should you use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` if you're modifying the GUI and you're in the AWT Event Dispatching Thread, such as an `ActionListener`?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Jeffrey Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: It still depends on what you're trying to accomplish. When you're in the `actionPerformed` method of an `ActionListener`, you are on the EDT. However, there are some cases where you need to perform some action after all other listeners are done processing the same event, in which case you should use `invokeLater`. So what are you trying to actually do?

Comment: @Jeffrey Mostly `JButton#setEnabled(boolean)` and adding/removing elements from a `JList`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must always do GUI updates in the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).  However, as Jeffrey points out in the comments, the `ActionListener.actionPerformed` method on a Swing object is *already* invoked from the EDT.

If you simply want the `JButton` to look enabled/unenabled or to add/remove items from a `JList`, and your making those changes via an `ActionListener` on a Swing component, then you shouldn't have to invoke `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` explicitly.

Comment: +1, If the OP was trying to clear a `JTextComponent` or re-position a `JScrollBar`, `invokeLater` may have been necessary. But seeing as he is only enabling/disabling a `JButton` and modifying a `JList`, it is not.

Comment: @Jeffrey Why would it of been necessary if I was doing that?

Comment: As long as we are in the EDT, using `invokeLater` is quite useless. Obviously if we want to run something at a later point in time, the same restrictions as usual apply (i.e. just because we start a thread from the EDT doesn't help us at all).

Comment: @Stripies Because the listeners that create the text in a `JTextComponent` may be notified after the current listener. If that's the case, you will be clearing a `JTextComponent` which doesn't yet have any text in it; a pointless action.